# How do I replace the values of a row in a dataframe in R by another value?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df (15000x13). There is a subset of columns called predictives. I want to replace all the values of predictives in the rows between 13000 and 14000 by 0. How can I do it?

Comment: try: `df$predictives[13000:14000] <- 0`

Comment: Also in the future, its best to add some example data, and what you have already tried.

Comment: but that is for a column called predictives, i meant a subset of columns

Comment: `df[13000:14000, predictives] <- 0` assuming `predictives` is a character vector of all the column names you want affected.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post a minimal reprex of your starting data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The data.table package would make quick work of this.  I'm taking a guess at original data structure, simplifying to 2 predictive & 2 outcome columns, then changing rows 80-90 out of 100 rows:

```
library(data.table)

DT<-data.table(PredictiveA=c(1:100),
  PredictiveB=c(101:110),
  OutcomeA=c(1:10^2),
  OutcomeB=c(101:110*2))

ColsToChange<-grep("Predictive",colnames( DT), value=TRUE)  #  gather   all columns with "Predictive" in column name

DT[80:90, (ColsToChange):= lapply(.SD, `==`, 0), .SDcols= ColsToChange]  #  select rows 80-90 then change the predictve columns to 0
DT
```

This yields:

```
 .......
 75:          75         105       75      210
 76:          76         106       76      212
 77:          77         107       77      214
 78:          78         108       78      216
 79:          79         109       79      218
 80:           0           0       80      220
 81:           0           0       81      202
 82:           0           0       82      204
 83:           0           0       83      206
 84:           0           0       84      208
 85:           0           0       85      210
 86:           0           0       86      212
 87:           0           0       87      214
 88:           0           0       88      216
 89:           0           0       89      218
 90:           0           0       90      220
 91:          91         101       91      202
 92:          92         102       92      204
 93:          93         103       93      206
 94:          94         104       94      208
 95:          95         105       95      210
 96:          96         106       96      212
 97:          97         107       97      214
 98:          98         108       98      216
 99:          99         109       99      218
100:         100         110      100      220
     PredictiveA PredictiveB OutcomeA OutcomeB
```